# Python - Check if an exact list item exists in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a string exactly in another string.

```
'-w'
```

And I have a few different string target formats below.

```
`string -w`
`string -wy`
`string -w string`
`string -wy string`
```

I've tried the basic check but it matches all of the above four strings, expected:

```
`if "-w" in string`
```

I've a tried regex pattern like below but it matches one of the above strings, again expected.

```
`-ks\s`
```

The expected outcome would be for `-w` to only be found in the below two strings.

```
`string -w`
`string -w string`
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `r'-w\b'` where `\b` is the word boundary. eg `re.search(r'-w\b', 'string -w')`. `\b` also matches EoL

Comment: Another possible sol is if '-w' in string.split()